# Build Tangent using Lengyel’s Method but not correct

Tags: c++, matrix

screen shoot:http://1drv.ms/1C9fgyl
pls note that the normal buffer is very strange. I use method in this link: http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html

the fabric tangent is very different between left half side and right half side.
I don't know what happen.

I test another sponza scene and put them in other guys who use same method to calc TBN and got same issue.
what's the bug in my algrithom?

```
bool OBJModel_Loader::BuildTangent(std::vector<OBJModel* >& Objects)
{
    for (OBJModel* actor : Objects)
    {
        PracEngLogf("BuildTangent For Model: %s! \n", actor->Name.c_str());
        int cnt = actor->VertexBuffer.size(); 
        PEVector3* tan1 = new PEVector3[cnt * 2];
        PEVector3* tan2 = tan1 + cnt;
        ZeroMemory(tan1, cnt*sizeof(PEVector3) * 2);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < actor->FaceInfos.size(); i+=3)
        {

            int Idx1 = actor->FaceInfos[i].VertexIdx;
            int Idx2 = actor->FaceInfos[i + 1].VertexIdx;
            int Idx3 = actor->FaceInfos[i + 2].VertexIdx;

            const PEFloat3& v1 = actor->VertexBuffer[Idx1];
            const PEFloat3& v2 = actor->VertexBuffer[Idx2];
            const PEFloat3& v3 = actor->VertexBuffer[Idx3];

            const PEFloat2& w1 = actor->UVs[actor->FaceInfos[i].UVIdx];
            const PEFloat2& w2 = actor->UVs[actor->FaceInfos[i+1].UVIdx];
            const PEFloat2& w3 = actor->UVs[actor->FaceInfos[i+2].UVIdx];

            PEVector3 E1(v2.X - v1.X, v2.Y - v1.Y, v2.Z - v1.Z);
            PEVector3 E2(v3.X - v1.X, v3.Y - v1.Y, v3.Z - v1.Z);

            PEFloat2 St1 ( w2.X - w1.X, w2.Y - w1.Y );
            PEFloat2 St2 ( w3.X - w1.X, w3.Y - w1.Y );
            PEVector3 sDir;
            PEVector3 tDir;

            float r = St1.X*St2.Y - St2.X*St1.Y;
            if (fabs(r) < 1e-6f)
            {
                sDir = PEVector3(1.0f, .0f, .0f);
                tDir = PEVector3(.0f, 1.0f, .0f);
            }
            else
            {
                r = 1.0f / r;

                sDir = PEVector3((St2.Y*E1.x - St1.Y*E2.x)*r, (St2.Y*E1.y - St1.Y*E2.y)*r, (St2.Y*E1.z - St1.Y*E2.z)*r);
                tDir = PEVector3((St1.X*E2.x - St2.X*E1.x)*r, (St1.X*E2.y - St2.X*E1.y)*r, (St1.X*E2.z - St2.X*E1.z)*r);
            }

            tan1[Idx1] += sDir;
            tan1[Idx2] += sDir;
            tan1[Idx3] += sDir;

            tan2[Idx1] += tDir;
            tan2[Idx2] += tDir;
            tan2[Idx3] += tDir;

        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < actor->FaceInfos.size(); i++)
        {
            int Idx = actor->FaceInfos[i].VertexIdx;
            const PEVector3& N = actor->VertexNormal[actor->FaceInfos[i].NormalIdx];
            const PEVector3& T = tan1[Idx];
            PEVector3 adjTangent = T - N * PEVector3::Dot(N, T);
            adjTangent.Normalize();
            actor->VertexTangent[Idx] = adjTangent;
            actor->VertexTangent[Idx].w = PEVector3::Dot(N.Cross(T), tan2[Idx]) < .0f ? -1.0f : 1.0f;
        }

        delete[] tan1;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it's not really well written or understandable as it's currently stated. I've also fixed your post for the "code" section.